# How a write a global non member post decremented overloaded operator?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading, friend

I am beginning to programming. I am stuck in this point so I hope you guys will help me.

When we write a post decrement member function the syntax for that is

```
     type type::operator--(int){}
```

But I want this to be a friend function so how can i write it?

This is for pre increment:

```
   friend Mystring &operator--(  Mystring &lhs);
```

What is the syntax for post incrementation?

Comment: Why do you need it to be a `friend` function?

Comment: i want to access the private members .

Comment: Let me rephrase that - why can't it be a member?

Comment: You should make it a member function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading

Comment: yes it's working in member function ,  but what is the syntax for global post increment/decrement ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
class type
{
// ...
    // postfix operator--
    friend type operator--(type &t, int){type t1; /* some logics */ return t1;}
};
```